# Display specific product attribute values on archives category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I want to show specific product attributes on category page in WooCommerce. Attributes would be shown after the product title, before the short description.

The attributes are **`pa_nopeus`**, **`pa_liito`**, **`pa_vakaus`** and **`pa_feidi`**. They are only numerical values. I just want to show the values and not the names, pretty much like this:

```
Product Name
4 / 4 / 1 / 2
Short description
```

If these values do not exist in the product, line would not be shown at all.

I want to add this to the (template) code and not by using a plugin. I believe it will be added to **`content-product.php.`**

```
#content-product.php start.... 

do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

VALUES HERE SOMEHOW?


/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

#rest of the content-product.php...
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The best way to do what you expect (without overriding the templates) is to use a function that we hook in **`'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title'`** hook.

*In this case the code below goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).*

Here is the code:

```
// For WooCommerce below version 3.0
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20 );
function custom_attributes_display(){

    // Just for product category archives pages
    if(is_product_category()){
        global $product;

        // the array of attributes names
        $attribute_names = array('pa_nopeus', 'pa_liito', 'pa_vakaus', 'pa_feidi');
        foreach( $attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name ) {

            // Getting the value of an attribute
            $attribute_value = array_shift(wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute_name));

            // Displays only if attribute exist for the product
            if(!empty($attribute_value) || $attribute_value == '0' ){ // Updated
                echo $attribute_value;

                // Separating each number by a " / "
                if($key < 3) echo ' / ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> For woocommerce 3.0+ see: [Add Attributes to Short Description in WooCommerce 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528392/add-woocommerce-attributes-to-short-description/)

So you will get just after the title, on product category archives pages what you are expecting.

---

Or alternatively you can use the code above in the template **`content-product.php`**, this way:

```
#content-product.php start.... 

do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' );

/////////////// HERE IS THE CODE ////////////////

// Just for product category archives pages
if(is_product_category()){
    global $product;

    // the array of attributes names
    $attribute_names = array('pa_nopeus', 'pa_liito', 'pa_vakaus', 'pa_feidi');
    foreach( $attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name ) {

        // Getting the value of an attribute
        $attribute_value = array_shift(wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute_name));

        // Displays only if attribute exist for the product
        if(!empty($attribute_value) || $attribute_value == '0' ){
            echo $attribute_value;

            // Separating each number by a " / "
            if($key < 3) echo ' / ';
        }
    }
}


/**
 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );

#rest of the content-product.php...
```

But the first solution is more recommended and elegant.

**The code is tested and works**

Comment: Thank you for both of these. I understand how this works. Tested both of these and worked the same way. I'll go with  `functions.php`. modification.

Only thing that did not work, it doesnt show value if it is 0 (it is still value, not "empty"). Should the code be little bit different?

Comment: @JuhaKytö OK I edit my code now, for that case… Ok changed the condition a little bit try it this way and tell me if it work for "0" value