# Add Attributes to Short Description in WooCommerce 3.0+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I would like to insert the attributes from all products to their short description, so the client can open a quickview and check this attributes.

I already tried this answer: [Display specific product attribute values on archives category pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580489/display-specific-product-attribute-values-on-archives-category-pages)

Also this one: [Woocommerce - Display single product attribute(s) with shortcodes in Frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394127/woocommerce-display-single-product-attributes-with-shortcodes-in-frontend)

And I wasn't able to make it work. I think it should be because WooCommerce got updated to version 3.0+

Does anyone know a way to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 3** ( Automation for simple products, WC compatibility )

```
// Compatibility for WC 3+ and automation enhancements
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20 );
function custom_attributes_display(){
    global $product;

    // Just for simple products
    if( ! $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) return;

    $loop_count = 0;

    echo '<div>';

    // Get the attributes taxonomy slugs (Updated and dynamic now)
    $attributes_taxonomy = $product->get_attributes();
    // OR set an indexed array of taxonomy slug (key) and name (value) to chose which ones, like:
    // $attributes_taxonomy = array('pa_nopeus' => 'Nopeus', 'pa_liito' => 'Liito, 'pa_vakaus' => 'Vaukaus' );

    foreach( $attributes_taxonomy as $taxonomy => $attribute ) {

        // Getting the term names of an attribute (set in a coma separated string if many values)
        $attribute_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        $terms_string = implode( ',', $attribute_terms );

        // Displays only if attribute exist for the product
        if( count( $attribute_terms ) > 0 ){ // Updated
            echo $terms_string;

            // Separating each number by a " | " (Updated and dynamic now)
            $attr_count = count( $attributes_taxonomy );
            $loop_count++;
            if( $loop_count < $attr_count && $attr_count > 1 ) echo ' | ';
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

---

**Update** For WooCommerce version 3.0+ only.

```
// For WooCommerce Version 3.0+ (only)
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20 );
function custom_attributes_display(){

    // Just for product category archives pages
    if(is_product_category()){
        global $product;

        // the array of attributes names
        $attribute_names = array('pa_nopeus', 'pa_liito', 'pa_vakaus', 'pa_feidi');
        foreach( $attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name ) {

            // For WooCommerce version 3.0+
            $product_id = $product->get_id(); // WC 3.0+

            // Getting the value of an attribute (OK for WC 3.0+)
            $wc_term = wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, $attribute_name);
            $attribute_value = array_shift($wc_term);

            // Displays only if attribute exist for the product
            if(!empty($attribute_value) || '0' == $attribute_value ){ // Updated
                echo $attribute_value;

                // Separating each number by a " / "
                if($key < 3) echo ' / ';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

It should work now in WC 3.0+

---

Related to this Answer code: [Display specific product attribute values on archives category pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580489/display-specific-product-attribute-values-on-archives-category-pages/39585849#39585849)

Comment: Since i am a newbie in php, i ussed a plugin to show the Attributes:
"WooCommerce Show Attributes" and it worked well

Answer (score 2):

to build off of LoicTheAztec's answer:

His code only works if you have predefined the attributes in the WP backend under Products -> Attributes. If you work with individual (custom) product attributes that you set up on the product page, wc_get_product_terms() won't return anything. You can recognize predefined attributes by the "pa_" prefix, they are stored in the "woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies" table.

In order to show these individual attributes in the same way as LoicTheAztec suggested, use this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_attributes_display', 20);
function custom_attributes_display()
{
    // Just for product category archive pages
    if(is_product_category())
    {
        global $product;

        // get all product attributes
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
        // the array of attributes you want to display (shown in same order)
        $show_attributes = array('My Attribute A', 'Another Attribute B');
        foreach($show_attributes as $key => $show_attribute)
        {
            foreach($attributes as $attribute)
            {
                // check if current attribute is among the ones to be shown
                if ($attribute->get_name() == $show_attribute)
                {
                    echo $attribute->get_options()[0];
                    // seperate attributes by "/"
                    if (count($show_attributes) > 1)
                        echo '/';
                    unset($show_attributes[$key]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do pretty much the same and found a one-liner solution that might help people dropping by here as I did. The following code works for me.

WooCommerce Version: 5+

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_atts_to_summary' );

function add_atts_to_summary() {
    global $product;
    wc_display_product_attributes( $product );
}
```